# Django does not let me to manually type PK with postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a model like this one.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
        id = models.IntegerField(
            primary_key=True,
        )
        is_active = models.BooleanField(
            default=True,
        )
```

I want to put an id by myself. However django-postgresql does not allow me to do it. Here is  my view:

```
class MyView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_model = MyModel()
        my_model.id = 6

        my_model.save()
```

It throws exception on the .save() part. Here is the exception text:

ProgrammingError at /myViews/myView

relation "myDB_mymodel" does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "myDB_mymodel" WHERE...

Comment: Seems you have not run database migrations yet. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: I did it. It works fine if I don't put the id manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways that you can do it:

```
my_model=MyModel(id=6)
my_model.save()
```

or

```
my_model=MyModel.objects.create(id=6)
```

Comment: It is not working with the first way however second way fixed the problem.